# Best practices of handling PageNotFound for unmapped request-mappings

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

**My use-case:**
I have multiple "kind of logical parts" in my application, that are separated by url. something like:
- someUrl/servletPath/**onePartOfMyApplication**/...
- someUrl/servletPath/**otherPartOfMyApplication**/...

Now I want to handle unmapped requests (404s) for each part differently.

**How I'm handling it now:**
my web.xml:

```
...
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/servletPath/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

my controller:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController
{
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  @RequestMapping(value = "/404.html")
  protected String show404Page(final HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    final String forward = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");

    // parse string and redirect to whereever, depending on context
    final String redirectPath = parse(forward);

    return "redirect: " + redirectPath;
  }
  ...
```

**My aim:**
Is there a more elegant (spring-like)-way of handling 404s, instead of parsing the request in a controller or interceptor and declaring the error-page in my web.xml?

Would be nice if my controller should could look something like this:

```
    @Controller
    public class ExceptionController
    {
      @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
      @RequestMapping(value = "/onePartOfMyApplication/404.html")
      protected String show404PageForOnePart(final HttpServletRequest request)
      {
        // do something
        ...
        return "onePartPage";
      }

      @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
      @RequestMapping(value = "/otherPartOfMyApplication/404.html")
      protected String show404PageForOtherPart(final HttpServletRequest request)
      {
        // do something different
        ...
        return "otherPartPage";
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use @ExceptionHandler annotation. In controller I have something like:

```
  private class ItemNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     public ItemNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
     }
  }

  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public void handleINFException(ItemNotFoundException ex) {

  }
```

And then I throw an exception either in Controller (or in Service layer):

```
  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  @ResponseBody
  public Item detail(@PathVariable int id) {
     Item item = itemService.findOne(id);
     if (item == null) { throw new ItemNotFoundException("Item not found!"); }
     return item;
  }
```

You can do anything you like in method annotated with @ExceptionHandler. Right now in my example it shows a standard 404 error which you can customize in web.xml, but you can do much, much more. See documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html

Comment: This is a good practice for cases where you have a mapping that goes 'bad'. But I'm looking for a solution to catch all other urls that arent't matched.

Comment: see this blog post: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: This is what I was reading before, very nice blog post But this article doesn't handle my problem. Or I'm missing something here. Please correct me.